# Как отсортировать массив объектов со связанными массивами?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив объектов такого типа:

```
const source = [
  {
    id: 1,
    price: ["100 р", "300 р", "200 р"],
    tariff: ["first", "third", "second"],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    price: ["200 р", "100 р", "300 р"],
    tariff: ["Dsa", "Qwe", "Cxz"],
  },
  // и т.д.
];
```

На выходе необходимо получить массив "source", но отсортированный по `price` или `tariff`.

Сложность в том, что `price[0]` условно связан с `tariff[0]`, так же как и `tariff[1]` с `price[1]`.

Так же, длины массивов `tariff` и `price` всегда одинаковые, т.е. у обоих length может быть как 3, так и 2 и 1.

В результате, если мы сортируем по `tariff` то получаем отсортированный `source`:

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    price: ["300 р", "200 р", "100 р"],
    tariff: ["Cxz", "Dsa", "Qwe"],
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    price: ["100 р", "200 р", "300 р"],
    tariff: ["first", "second", "third"],
  },
  // и т.д.
]
```

То есть мы сортируем и сам `source` и связанные вместе `tariff` и `price`.

Comment: вместо того чтобы так мучиться. лучше создайте ключ например "tariffs" в котором будет массив объектов name + price.  и тогда достаточно будет сортировать например по name и во вторых будут данные сгруппированы, что будет более корректно

Comment: большой вопрос: не ясно на что должна ориентирвоаться сортировка для source.... каковы критерии сортировки

Comment: критерий следующий, сортируя по `tariff` мы сортируем сам `tariff` по алфавиту, а потом взяв `tariff[0]` сортируем сам исходный массив `source`

Comment: @Igor, мы сортируя по `tariff` по сути сортируем `source` по первому элементу `tariff`, а потом уже `tariff` внутри?

Comment: @Meth0d, не совсем, сначала сортируем все `tariff`, а потом уже по первому элементу, но сложность в другом, там идёт условная привязка к `price`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const source = [
    {
        id: 1,
        price: ["100 р", "300 р", "200 р"],
        tariff: ["first", "third", "second"],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        price: ["200 р", "100 р", "300 р"],
        tariff: ["Dsa", "Qwe", "Cxz"],
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        price: ["500 р", "700 р", "1000 р"],
        tariff: ["elc", "dde", "intel"],
    },
]

function sortIt(arr, type) {
    return structuredClone(arr)
        .sort((a, b) => {
            a = a[type][0]
            b = b[type][0]

            if (a > b) return 1
            else if (a < b) return -1
            else return 0
        })
        .map(el => {
            el[type] = el[type].sort()

            return el
        })
}

console.log(sortIt(source, 'tariff'))
console.log(sortIt(source, 'price'))
```

Comment: Спасибо, но немного не то, в вашем примере нет связи между `price` и `tariff`, под связью, я имею введу, что к примеру тариф `intel` имеет цену `1000 р`, и если мы отсортируем по убыванию цены, получив `price[0] == 1000 р`, то и `tariff[0]` должен стать `intel`  как это было до сортировки

Comment: я понял. в таком случае лучше, если возможно, переделать структуру данных на что то типа: [{price: '200 p', name: 'intel'}, ...]. Все станет гораздо проще - они будут действительно связаны уже структурно